# Classes não carregam! Script roda no xampp mas não roda em LAMP/LEMP/VPS

Tags: php, mvc, classes, include, lamp

Galera, fiz um script bem leve e simples.

No xampp ele roda normal, mas quando subo para qualquer servidor não vai de jeito nenhum.

Já tentei no *lamp*, *lemp* (Da Digital Ocean), no *VPS* (Da Dreamhost), mas realmente não vai.

A primeira classe a dar erro era a `config`, mas copiei ela direto no *controller* ai funcionou.

No `log`, recebo este erro:

> [Mon Jan 29 04:21:41.390298 2018] [:error] [pid 15756] [client 76.4.107.182:50472] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'Paginas' not found in /var/www/html/partners/controllers/paginaController.php:10\nStack trace:\n#0 /var/www/html/partners/core/Core.php(46): paginaController->index('home')\n#1 /var/www/html/partners/index.php(23): Core->run()\n#2 {main}\n  thrown in /var/www/html/partners/controllers/paginaController.php on line 10

Meu xampp é php 5.6
Instalei um servidor novo com php 5.6 também, e nao roda do mesmo jeito.

o xampp vem com mais coisas habilitadas?

Comment: Você programou em Windows provavelmente, e jogou em um *vps linux*, talvez seja o famoso **case insensitive**

Comment: Fica difícil da uma melhor resposta sem seu codigo, o que o Guilherme disse é bem possivel, se não for o caso verifique a versão do PHP. Tem certas funções que foram descontinuadas, o próprio __autoload não funciona no PHP 7.2. As vezes é o contrario, você desenvolveu um código moldado no PHP7 e subiu pra um servidor com uma versão inferior, o que pode gerar falhas fatais como é o caso. Coloca um arquivo com a função phpinfo(); no localhost e online e compara as carateristas de cada servidor, caso sejam iguais poste aqui seu código de carregamento de classes.

Comment: Vou abrir o phpinfo das duas e vejo qual a diferença e retorno aqui !

Comment: Mudei a versão do php e o problema persiste ! =(

Comment: Tá usando padrão MVC? algum framework? Poste o código que faz o request das páginas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Descobri, era o sensitive mesmo !

as classes estavam com a primeira letra minuscula, por isso não achava!

Obrigado a todos !